# JQuery image not changing on click correctly

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this working so that when the menu is clicked it displays a element underneath it. I also want there to be an image that changes from displaying an arrow pointing right to an arrow pointing left.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var background = $('#background_container').attr('display');
  
  $("div#1_open").click(function(){

    $("div#background_container").toggle()
      if(background = 'none'){
        $('#1_arrow').attr('src' , './resources/images/icons/left.png');
      }else{
  $('#1_arrow').attr('src' , './resources/images/icons/right.png'); 
      };
    });  
});
```

```css
.header{
 width:300px;
 margin:10px 0px;
 height:40px;
 color:grey;
 font-family:monospace;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:40px;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin-left:10px;
 cursor:pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
 -o-user-select: none; 
 user-select: none;
}
.arrow{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin-right:10px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="background">
     <div class="header" id="1_open"><img src="./resources/images/icons/right.png" class="arrow" id="1_arrow">Background</div>
        <div id="background_container" style="display:none;"> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Didn't try or anything else.. But I think that if(background = 'none') is wrong, should use "=="

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //var background = $('#background_container').attr('display');

 $("div#1_open").click(function(){
    $("div#background_container").slideToggle(0 , function(){
      var background = $(this).attr('display');
      if(background == 'none'){
        $('#1_arrow').attr('src' , './resources/images/icons/left.png');
      }else{
        $('#1_arrow').attr('src' , './resources/images/icons/right.png');   
      }
    }); 
  });       
});
```

Comment: I made a mistake with not using css instead of attr but that was the only issue. 
Thanks for your help